# OpenSSL s_server no tls1.1 and s_client no tls1 gives error

Tags: ssl, openssl

Can someone explain this behavior:

If I run an s_server with:

```
openssl s_server -key privateKey.key -cert certificate.crt -msg -no_tls1_1
```

And an s_client with:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -msg -no_tls1
```

I receive on the client:

```
3073448136:error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol:s23_clnt.c:697:
```

And just Error on the server.
I find this very strange since they should be able to communicate over some other protocol except tls1 and tls1.1, for example ssl3 should work.

I am currently running OpenSSL 1.0.1 from 14 March 2012 (it's old I know, but is this really a bug, it feels like something I have not understood about OpenSSL)

Comment: works for me without problems. openssl 1.0.1e. It uses SSLv3

Comment: Weird, might be a bug in the first version of 1.0.1 after all then.